# Remoteapp and slow network Drives

Tags: remoteapp

Bit of a Newby here.  I have an RDS farm ( 3 x Server 2008 r2) in testing and on a remote site Thin pc ( cut down windows 7) running Remoteapp . The usual office etc. . Now if you go file open and browse to a network folder and say a word file all is rosy and is very quick and Swift. But if you browse to the network drive through a shortcut on the desktop say and go to the same file it takes upwards of a minute to open and comes up with \tsclient\u:And path name . and processing .
Also if you open windows explorer and enter the correct unc path to the file it opens very quickly.
Am relatively new to Remote app so am a trifle confused.

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut on the desktop appears to be a shortcut to the document from the users redirected U: drive. When the user opens the document from the desktop shortcut it's actually opening from the redirected U: drive from the clients local machine. That's why it takes so long. Accessing files from a redirtected drive in an RDS session has to go over the network that separates the client from the server. Based on the fact that the client has a locally mapped drive to a network share that's common to the RDS server (because they can access the same document from their redirected client drive and by browsing the network in the RDS session) tells me that they're on the same network, whether they're directly connected or connected via a VPN of some sort. Is that the case?

Also, the clue is in the fact that the path to the desktop shortcut is `\\tsclient\u:`. The `\\tsclient` tells you that it's a file on a redirected drive.

Comment: Sorry , For being Unclear . Yes everything is on the same corporate network . The RDS Servers and the network share server reside on the same 10 gig backbone the client is on an extremely slow vpn in to our infrastructure.

Comment: That's the problem then. The client has a locally mapped drive to the network share through the slow VPN, right? The desktop shortcut is actually a shortcut to the document from the redirected local drive in the session. Whenever they access the document from that shortcut they're opening it from the redirected drive so it's opening through the VPN connection. Delete that shortcut and create a shortcut from the share or mapped drive IN the session, NOT from the redirected drive.

Comment: Thank you Very Much that worked perfectly Now Ill have to get the UNC path Shortcuts to show up with a script . Once Again thank You.  Andy

Comment: Glad to help...